# How to cascade register correctly?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, shift-register

Currently I have this 4 bit CPU as shown in the schematic diagram below.
[image]

What I wish to achieve:

- Add one more output register to make the CPU output a total of 8 bits
- Show alphabet using the 8 bits output

My current trial:

- Cout of the first IC connected to Cin of the second IC
- Cascaded in a synchronous fashion
  [image]

What I unsure/don't understand:

- Should I connect the A~D pins of the second register to ALU?
- The LOAD-bar pin is connected to LO-bar of the ALU. Should I add one more LO-bar to the ALU and connect it to the LOAD-bar of the second register?